# How do I resize a partition on an img file?

Tags: partition, disk-image, puppy-linux

I have a puppy linux img that is 8gb but I need it to fit on a 6gb drive. How do I resize the ext2 partition on the img?

Answer (score 9):

*NOTE* Make a backup, anything can go wrong ...
I ran all those as root :

1. bind a loop device to the image: `losetup /dev/loop10 $image_file`
2. refresh partitions: `partprobe /dev/loop10`
3. adjust partition size: `gparted /dev/loop10`
4. undo the loop: `losetup -d /dev/loop10`
5. remove unwanted space: `truncate -s -${SIZE}G $image_file` (you might want to calculate the exact size based on values from `fdisk`/`cfdisk` * `sector size`)

*NOTE* You might need to double check the partitions' UUIDs, mine seem to have changed and I had to update `fstab`

Comment: Isn't the truncate command eg. like this: `truncate -s 6GB /yourimagefile.img` or `truncate -s 6442450944 /yourimagefile.img`? But even though I took the end sector and multiplied by the sector size it must somehow have been wrong, because afterwards `parted` told me "Can't have partition outside the disk" and the image doesn't work...

Comment: Also, the `resizepart` command in `parted` was very quick (I used `parted` instead of `gparted`). Does it just cut of the partition at the given size? What if files are "physically" located outside the partition boundary - will they just be discarded?

Comment: for fdisk, taking into account only the end sector is not exact. The right calculation is: ( start_sector + partition_sector_count) * sector_size. You use this amount A (in bytes) for truncate: `truncate --size={A} $image_file `

Comment: This answer works great, but the truncate line kept throwing an error.  So I added the approximate sizes of the partitions plus a 10M safety margin (eg. truncate -s 250M my.img) and that worked great and left a little unallocated space at the end of the last partition.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to shrink the filesystem - any kind of logical volume management or similar containers - then the image. I'm going to assume you're talking about a RAW disk image.

## Steps at a glance:

- Ensure the image is not being accessed (ex: `lsof`)
- Shrink the filesystem (ex: `resize2fs`)
- Perform a filesystem check (ex: `fsck`)
- Shrink any LVM or other kind of containers (if needed)
- Shrink the disk image (ex: dd to a new image with skip or use `qemu-img`)
- Fsck again, test that it works!

## Alternative:

- Create a new image and copy the data / MBR / etc. over.
- Clone the image with something like [partclone](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Partclone)

## Similar questions:

- https://superuser.com/questions/24838/is-it-possible-to-resize-a-qemu-disk-image

## Reference:

- http://lnx.cx/docs/vdg/html/ch02s02.html
- https://major.io/2010/12/14/mounting-a-raw-partition-file-made-with-dd-or-dd_rescue-in-linux/
- http://www.tehfear.com/2007/10/08/resize-loop-disk-image/
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_cloning

Comment: no need to assume as they stated "img file" not image file, but despite that, i am not able to follow your steps, can you elaborate on how to make my 2TB .img file to 1TB ?